# Two visibly identical strings are considered not equal by SQL Server and Excel

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2005, duplicates

This is perhaps too simple, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a simple SELECT DISTINCT statement which returns two rows: CODE and DESCRIPTION

They are identical like this:

```
00065        Stmt to Party 2-4 pgs
00065        Stmt to Party 2-4 pgs
```

However, the DISTINCT in the SELECT statement never filters the duplicate one out. I tried pasting these two values in Excel 2010 and attempted to use the "Remove duplicate" function, no use; I also tried a simple formula like this: =IF(D337=D338,"X","Y") and the result was always "Y".

AutoFilter in Excel also indicated that these strings are different.

The lengths of the strings are equal, as tested with SQL Server LEN(DESCRIPTION) function. There were no invisible special characters in them either.

How do I find out *what* is different between these two strings? Please note that I used Excel for testing/troubleshooting purpose only.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you convert to bytes in the 2 strings? E.G. here http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx Certainly what you have pasted here looks identical - but may not be the same as what you have at source.

Comment: @Caribou Wow, You are right; Thank you so much. they result in two slightly different encoded strings. What next?

Comment: Well - where did they come from and why are they different :) I can't answer that - I would assume if you need to correct them then you can do a manual update (query) so that the one that isn't correct is?

Comment: It sounds like someone is copying text from the web, Word or some other text formatting app into your database.  It is important for your database client apps to filter out text junk like this (unless you really do want it in your db).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an offline hex editor, or an online facility such as http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx and compare the bytes in the two strings. Then you should see if they are identical. (From comment above)

You could then do a manual query where you update the database by either deleting or updating the string to get the value consistent.

Comment: The blank space was represented by hex 20 in one and hex a0 in another. Do you know what the difference between these two is?

Comment: @FMFF: 0xA0 is a non-breaking space

Comment: Apologies @FMFF i'm afraid I had to go to bed - hope you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

Try casting as nvarchar, then take the distinct values.  Works in some cases...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).